# Feeding input to a program with Perl?

Tags: perl

I am not sure how to put this question. I am trying to write a Perl program which invokes a child program (a Fortran program) so child program goes to stdin to get yes/no.

Is there a way Perl can give that option, without letting child goes to STDIN?

Because of my poor programming vocabulary, I couldn't get an answer from Google.

Comment: If the other program uses stdin to get its input then what is the question for perl?  It sounds like what you are asking is for a way to stop making the fortran program use stdin?

Comment: It sounds like you want to drive another program, with the Perl program acting a bit like 'you' and the Fortran program asking questions and receiving responses.  You should take a look at Expect.pm.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471018/how-can-i-control-an-interactive-unix-application-programmatically-through-perl

Comment: @Alex thats what exactly i am trying to do. thanks. I would probably stick with pipes as suggested by ysth, since its a small script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a progam with its input coming from a pipe like so:

```
open my $ftn_input, '|-', $fortran_program
    or die "Couldn't start $fortran_program: $!";
if ($yes) {
    print $ftn_input "Yes\n";
}
else {
    print $ftn_input "No\n";
}
close($ftn_input) # waits for fortran program to complete
    or die "Program failed; error $!, wait status $?\n";
```